# Django database with router returns a count, but no records

Tags: django, multi-database

I have a django-orm database populated with data collected in spreadsheets. I am trying to write a diff function to check the current state of the database against the contents of a spreadsheet. I load the data from the spreadsheet using a router to put it into a temporary, sqlite database (the 'default' database is postgres), Here's my router:

```
reference_models = ['Stimulus'] # these values are fixed 
load_models = ['Response', 'Participant'] # these values vary per spreadsheet

class TestRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.object_name in reference_models:
            return 'default'
        else:
            assert model._meta.object_name in load_models
            return 'test'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        assert model._meta.object_name not in reference_models
        return 'test'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == "test":
            return True
        return None
```

Test from my diff script:

```
print("---> there are", Response.objects.all().using("default").count(), "original Response objects")
print(Response.objects.all().using("default").select_related("participant"))
print("---> there are", Response.objects.all().count(), "temporary Response objects")
print(Response.objects.all())
```

The output of this is:

```
---> there are 137709 original Response objects
[ ## LOTS OF OBJECTS ##, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
---> there are  1680 temporary Response objects
[]
```

Why is this final query empty, if the `.count()` method finds 1680 objects?

**EDIT** Here is some bonus diagnostic information (using `from IPython import embed` to look at the state of the script while it is running):

```
In [16]: print Response.objects.all().query
SELECT "data_response"."id", "data_response"."modified", "data_response"."created", 
"data_response"."stimulus_id", "data_response"."participant_id", "data_response"."full_response",
"data_response"."full_response_orthography" FROM "data_response" INNER JOIN "data_stimulus" ON 
("data_response"."stimulus_id" = "data_stimulus"."id") INNER JOIN "data_participant" ON 
("data_response"."participant_id" = "data_participant"."id") ORDER BY "data_stimulus"."task" ASC, 
"data_stimulus"."number" ASC, "data_participant"."code" ASC
```

I suppose the problem is that the Stimulus object is a foreign key, and the router is getting confused where to read from. I can however pull up a Response object by id in the ipython console, and then get its Stimulus as a regular attribute (`r = Response.objects.get(id=123)` then `s = r.stimulus`).

**another EDIT** I've hacked together a functional but unsatisfying solution using:

```
responses = []
for response in Response.objects.raw("""select * from data_response"""):
    responses.append(response)
```

I don't know why this works and `Response.objects.all()` doesn't.